# AS3: How can I get the top-left and exact width and height of some text in a text field?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

We are trying to get a `Rectangle` that represents the exact* boundary of the text in a `TextField`.

**Exact as possible.*

Take this image:

[image]

Using my current knowledge, I can retrieve the **blue** rectangle above like so:

```
var textRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(
    field.x,
    field.y,
    field.textWidth,
    field.textHeight
);
```

However, we need to get as close as possible to the **red** rectangle (I realize there will be minor differences because characters have varied with/height and there will need to be a common ground).

How can I get the red rectangle (dynamically)?

---

I set up this helper class based on the answer below by Jacob Eggers, however I always get a result of `(x=0, y=0, w=0, h=0)`..

```
package
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class TextBounds
    {

        public static function getTextBounds(textField:TextField):Rectangle
        {
            var curtainColor:uint = 0x00FF00;
            var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(textField.width, textField.height, false, curtainColor);
            bmd.draw(textField);

            return bmd.getColorBoundsRect(curtainColor, textField.textColor, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Even if I fill a small section with the color I'm looking for I still get a zero-sized rectangle:

```
bmd.fillRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30), textField.textColor);
```

Comment: have you looked at ? : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharBoundaries()

Comment: @MartyWallace, if the solution posted below by Jacob Eggers does not solve the posted question, please unmark it as an answer of the question because this misleads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use BitmapData.draw, and then use [`getColorBoundsRect`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getColorBoundsRect%28%29) to get the bounds of the black text.
Something like this:

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(80, 40, false, 0xFFFFFF);
bmd.draw(tf)

var maskColor:uint = 0xFFFFFF; 
var color:uint = 0x000000;  //the color of the text
var tfBounds:Rectangle = bmd.getColorBoundsRect(maskColor, color, true);
trace(tfBounds);
```

---

**edit** good catch zachzurn about the text color. I added a comment to clarify.

Comment: That's a very clever solution.

Comment: I gave this a try, but I'm always getting a rectangle of size 0. I've posted my code in an update of my question - is there anything noticeably wrong? I also added a Bitmap representation of the generated BitmapData to the stage and it looks as expected (green block with my text on it).

Comment: I posted a solution to this on your new question.

Comment: You can also use [`paletteMap()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#paletteMap())

Comment: Make sure that the color you use in var color:uint is the color of the text. If you don't you will get the rectangle with no dimensions.

Comment: if the text field is set to Anti-alias for readability, you'll get a rectangle with zero width and height. set to Anti-alias for animation, you're good. http://www.allquests.com/question/4098555/getColorBoundsRect-doesnt-work-in-Player-9.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this, although is not going to be perfect:

```
var textRect:Rectangle = field.getBounds(field.parent);
```

Or try this (there's an example there you can try out):

http://blog.stroep.nl/2009/11/getbitmapbounds/

Comment: Nice idea, though `getBounds()` returns a Rectangle that represents the entirety of the TextField (even larger than the blue rectangle above).