# How to make TextField gutter less?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am looking for a solution to make `TextField` Object gutter less such that the `getBounds()` and `getColorBounds()` give the same rectangle. In short the `Rectangle` returned by `getBounds()` must start from first character's left-most pixel and end at last character's right-most pixel.

Comment: What is `getColorBounds()`? Is it anything you wrote by yourself? If no, please provide a link to this function's manual.

Comment: Also, you can try `textWidth` property, or `getLineMetrics()` to retrieve the needed dimensions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596529/as3-how-can-i-get-the-top-left-and-exact-width-and-height-of-some-text-in-a-tex

Comment: Sorry. Its ['getColorBoundsRect()'](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getColorBoundsRect%28%29) in the BitmapData class. getLineMetrics() will return what is already set. I want to set those values.

Like If I want my characters to be of 40px height and if I set the TextField's height to be 40, the actual character height will be less than 40. How can I manage it?

Comment: Use `setTextFormat()` and `defaultTextFormat` properties to manage formatting within a TextField. But, it won't be as easy with a customly tailored font to properly adjust formatting to match actual pixels, especially if your TextField is scaled somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use textWidth and textHeigth properties to do the thing you want, these values contains exactly you need.

Comment: No they don't. They are almost _exactly_ the same as getBounds(), width, height, LineMetrics, etc. methods and do not offer a properly positioned (x,y). Create a quick project and draw borders using getBounds() and textWidth/textHeight on a font at size 150. The latter is ~5px smaller than getBounds(). See [this screenshot](http://content.screencast.com/users/jjanusch/folders/Jing/media/4b81e085-b57f-40a2-aec8-7afa1c084666/2013-04-10_1415.png). REd = textWidth/Height, blue = getBounds

Comment: Well! It doesn't solve my problem either. You can see there are still some space at left & top of text inside blue border. Let me elaborate my Q that I want to set the actual text width & height. I don't want to get it, I can get it anytime using getColorBoundsRect() of the BitmapData Class. Please suggest me a solution to set it.